# Join at criteriaBuilder do not want to work correctly

Tags: spring-boot, predicate, criteria-api

I`m working on JPA specification, which must make a select ased on what i input.
I have Entity **Department** which have field **code** looks like **DB001**..

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Employee> departments;
```

Also **Employee**

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Department department;
```

And my test controller for employee

```
    @GetMapping("/employee")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
        final List<SearchData> searchDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        searchDataList.add(new SearchData("name", "Ivan"));
        searchDataList.add(new SearchData("code", "01"));
        return employeeService.getDynamicEmployeeSearch(searchDataList);
    }
```

When i open this in browser it say to me

```
Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [name] on this ManagedType [com.mentor.jpa.dynamicquery.domain.Department]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [name] on this ManagedType [com.mentor.jpa.dynamicquery.domain.Department]
```

I understand, that attribute name exist only at **Employee** entity, and not exist on **Department**, but i need to make a select with twose two criterias, so they need to work both. (When i try one criteria or criterias which do not need a join, they work!)

What should i change at my **Specification** code to make join work correctrly. My code at **Specification**

```
@Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<Employee> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                 final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        if (searchData != null) {
            return criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root
                            .join("department")
                            .get(searchData.getFieldName())
                            .as(String.class)),
                    "%" + searchData.getValue().toLowerCase() + "%");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

P.S. class **SearchData** is simple pojo with

```
private String fieldName;
private String value;
```

And also my method from Employee service

```
public List<Employee> getDynamicEmployeeSearch(List<SearchData> searchDataList) {
        List<Employee> employeesList = new ArrayList<>();
        Specification<Employee> specification = new EmployeeSpecification();
        if (searchDataList != null) {
            for (SearchData data : searchDataList) {
                specification = Specification.where(specification).and(new EmployeeSpecification(data));
            }
            employeesList = employeeRepository.findAll(specification);
            return employeesList;
        }
        return employeesList;
    }
```

I need to return Employees with name (or it part which i enter at SearchData, AND with Department code which i enter in second SearchData, but that code is at another table which has relations OneToMany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.
Wrote switch in toPredicate and add another one predicate, and when now i have criteria from department it will select department, when criteria from employee it will select employee.
In List i have correct data. Just thought that maybe something default exist for this.